# Do dramatic cases of body shaking and trembling in religious settings have supernatural causes?

Tags: physiology, religion, spirituality

There are many examples of people experiencing dramatic body shaking and trembling in religious settings, such as the ones below:

- [Example 1](https://youtu.be/FbtFNUULEqo?t=230)
- [Example 2](https://youtu.be/yKnxWl8500k?t=151)
- [Example 3](https://youtu.be/4aix9SlcLrE?t=406)
- [Example 4](https://youtu.be/BI6MDAbD25k?t=517)
- [Example 5](https://youtu.be/0iunSt3d3KQ?t=130)
- [Example 6](https://youtu.be/kD3g5rg0CqE?t=120)
- [Example 7](https://youtu.be/8DyykUq3sCU?t=304)
- [Example 8](https://youtu.be/xxL71A6rq3M?t=388)
- [Example 9](https://youtu.be/sowJFlY6CVs?t=182)
- [Example 10](https://youtu.be/YyTLtoQt8LU?t=172)
- [Example 11](https://youtu.be/FyBXj6zVwUE?t=48)
- [Example 12](https://youtu.be/FyBXj6zVwUE?t=131)
- [Example 13](https://youtu.be/RKgl07Nu-8w?t=100)
- [Example 14](https://youtu.be/Ppk1uoy-OdA?t=140)
- [Example 15](https://youtu.be/VEi8rWLdf-o?t=70)

Moreover, even children are experiencing this (like [here](https://youtu.be/RKgl07Nu-8w?t=101), [here](https://youtu.be/8zv44JvuTqk?t=268), [here](https://youtu.be/fTqkpjmW9ZI?t=124), [here](https://youtu.be/8zv44JvuTqk?t=273)), very old people (like [here](https://youtu.be/YVcTCooxEFY?t=181), [here](https://youtu.be/8zv44JvuTqk?t=293)) and even [prison inmates](https://youtu.be/y15LiY3Q8e0?t=212), which makes me doubt they are actors.

Many people claim they are the result of a supernatural influence acting upon these individuals. Here are some quotes from first-hand experiencers of the phenomenon:

- [Testimony 1](https://youtu.be/4aix9SlcLrE): this is by far the best testimony I know of. The context is the [Brownsville Revival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownsville_Revival). In the video a lady testifies about her experience of body shaking and trembling allegedly as a manifestation of the Holy Spirit acting upon her. In fact she begins to shake and tremble on camera as she is narrating her testimony. At [6:46](https://youtu.be/4aix9SlcLrE?t=406) the lady and the preacher begin to talk specifically about the causes of her tremors. At [7:12](https://youtu.be/4aix9SlcLrE?t=432) she says "[...]like right now, **I think the Glory of God is so strong up here, my body can't really take it and that's why I'm doing this** [...]"
- [Testimony 2](https://youtu.be/svpToEmqPEA): The testimony as a whole is powerful, but regarding body shaking and trembling at [4:54](https://youtu.be/svpToEmqPEA?t=294) the guy describes his experience. Here a quote: "[...] my body started doing things that defied metaphysics, **my body started doing things that I couldn't explain**. **I started levitating and bouncing off of the chair I was sitting in like a jack hammer** [...]"
- [Testimony 3](https://youtu.be/Ppk1uoy-OdA?t=122): "[...]I felt an electricity, a fire[...]" followed by the girl trembling and fainting in reaction to the command of the preacher. Then the preacher says "The power of God is the kingdom of God manifesting in our midst[...]".
- [Testimony 4](https://youtu.be/VEi8rWLdf-o?t=71): "[...]I felt an electricity all through my body, in all of my joints[...]", followed by the woman trembling and fainting in reaction to the command of the preacher (just like in the previous testimony).
- [Testimony 5](https://youtu.be/lii9TcDlTwc?t=118): "[...]I felt a heat, and I felt a peace[...]", followed by the woman trembling and fainting in reaction to the command of the preacher (again).
- [Testimony 6](https://youtu.be/lii9TcDlTwc?t=125): "[...]I felt a vibrating that I'm feeling right now[...]", followed by the guy fainting and feeling a sort of ecstasy based on his facial expression, in response to the preacher's command.
- [Testimony 7](https://youtu.be/YyTLtoQt8LU?t=144): "[...]I was burning all over, and I felt so free, He just embraces you and makes you feel so loved[...]", followed by the guy losing the equilibrium and fainting, in response to the preacher's command.

So we have live recordings of people dramatically shaking and trembling, and multiple first-hand testimonies claiming these manifestations are supernaturally caused.

Are these supernatural manifestations?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110621/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-does-body-shaking-and-trembl). I've moved comments discussing this question's *topic*. Those things belong in chat, please. Comments that remain are trying to improve the question.

Comment: This post is in [Psychology.SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25631/7604) and has been open for a while

Comment: This has had a [meta-question asked about it](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/correct-way-to-ask-questions-about-claims-involving-the-supernatural-or-the-meta). If you want to discuss whether it is on-topic, take it there. Anything else **[TAKE TO THE CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110621/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-does-body-shaking-and-trembl)**. Comments here are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Reminder: If you can't answer this question with empirical evidence, it is okay to leave it unanswerable. If you try to answer that it *is* supernatural, it will have to have some amazing references to not get instantly deleted.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I did the last edit because of Oddthinking's objections to the first testimony ([check out the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110621/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-does-body-shaking-and-trembl)), I wanted to explicitly quote a sentence where the lady claimed that the shaking was supernaturally caused (instead of being caused by a long-standing medical condition). I promise not to make further edits.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator please stop editing this question to add/re-arrange examples. The examples you have already are more than sufficient.